# Test checkout of feature 'Compiler' failed under MATLAB

Tags: matlab-compiler

I'm trying to convert my MATLAB program to .exe using MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b) but I couldn't because my MATLAB license number is unknown I got this error [image]

[image]

I don't know how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code directly: see [the code formatting help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for additional information

Comment: Also, if this a licensing issue, you should probably contact MATLAB support.

Comment: Yes I've verified this using License commande I got the answer unkown knowing that I use MATLAB Version: 8.2.0.701 (R2013b) how do I resolve this without contacting Matlab support

Comment: I have even verified the licence using  license('test','compiler') and it gave me 1 what should I do ?